# Basic bash programming

Tags: bash

How do I write functions in bash to perform the following tasks:

- Count the number of .pdf  files in a directory called myDir.
- Print out the n-th line of a file called data.txt, where n is a variable that stores an integer.
- Run the script userinput.o , which expects data from STDIN. However, you must provide data from a  file input.txt instead of from the terminal.
- Compare the contents of two  files foo1.txt and foo2.txt.  If the  files match, print"Files are simliar.".  If not,print"Files are different."
  .  Suppress all other output.
- Compile the  file windows8.c with the gcc compiler and redirect both STDERR and STDOUT to the file compile.out.

This is code I have for it:

```
function part_a 
{               


    return                      
}                               

function part_b
{              

    return                     
}                              

function part_c
{
    "input.txt">>"userinput.o"
    return
}

function part_d
{
    diff foo1.txt foo2.txt
    if (( $? != 0 ))
    then
        echo " Files are different. "
    else
        echo " Files are similar. " 
        return
}

function part_e
{
    gcc "windows8.c" -o quick_sim
    make &> compile.out
    return
}

# To test your function, you can call it below like this:

part_c
part_d
```

thanks :)

Comment: so are we supposed to just write the code or is there a specific issue you are having?

Comment: bit like a homework!

Comment: I am trying to run these function but am unable to do so. How do functions work in bash? Not homework its a practice exam :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Count the number of .pdf files in a directory called myDir.

```
val=`find myDir -type f -name '*.pdf'|wc -l`
```

count will save in `val` file.

> Print out the n-th line of a file called data.txt, where n is a variable that stores an integer.

```
awk -v line_no=$lineno 'NR==line_no' data.txt
```

where `lineno` is your variable

> Run the script userinput.o , which expects data from STDIN. However, you must provide data from a file input.txt instead of from the terminal.

```
userinput.o < input.txt
```

> Compare the contents of two files foo1.txt and foo2.txt. If the files match, print"Files are simliar.". If not,print"Files are different." . Suppress all other output.

```
diff -q foo1.txt foo2.txt >/dev/null && echo Files are similar || echo Files are differet
```

> Compile the file windows8.c with the gcc compiler and redirect both STDERR and STDOUT to the file compile.out.

gcc windows8.c 2&1> compile.out